# javascript to convert text tree to table

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, tree

I have a textual tree like this

```
A
:...A1
:   A2
B
:...B1
:   :...B11
:       B12
:       :...B121
:           B122
C
:...C1
    :...C11
        :...C111
            C112
```

I want to convert it to array like this using regex and javascript

```
ID,ParentID
A,null
A1,A
A2,A
B,null
B1,B
B11,B1
B12,B1
B121,B12
B122,B12
C,null
C1,C
C11,C1
C111,C11
C112,C11
```

What should be the most efficient way?

Comment: How did you decide that regex is the tool to use?

Comment: Regex is not a magical tool that can resolve every text problem. Specifically, it won't help you resolve problems it was not designed to solve.

Comment: I apologize for incomplete question, I have added javascript to question text..

Comment: ask yourself the harder question guys: can it be done with regex? :)